# How to specify AWS region in CloudFormation VPC

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-vpc

Reading through the [AWS CloudFormation VPC docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-resource-ec2-vpc.html), I'm not seeing how/where I specify the *region* to create the VPC in. Any ideas as to how this configuration works?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You specify the region you're deploying to with your [CLI credentials / profile](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/cli-configure-files.html) rather than in the CloudFormation template. This makes it easier to deploy the same template to different regions.

**~/.aws/credentials**

```
[default]
aws_access_key_id=AKIAIOSFODNN7EXAMPLE
aws_secret_access_key=wJalrXUtnFEMI/K7MDENG/bPxRfiCYEXAMPLEKEY
```

**~/.aws/config**

```
[default]
region=us-west-2
output=json
```